# jQuery having one button in multiple lists hiding/showing items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a button for my webshop filters. There are multiple 'categories' in one filter. One category will never display more than 5 items, no matter how many there are.

The button I need will allow the user to display more than the default of 5 items per category. In other words, if there are 7 items in the given category only 5 will be shown. The remaining 2 will be hidden. When the button is clicked all 7 items will be shown.

I've tried to do this but when I press the button it will show the items of the other categories as well..

```js
var count = $('.block-layered-nav .block-content dl dd ul li').length;

if (count > 5) {
  $('.showmore').show();
  $('.block-layered-nav .block-content dl dd ul li:gt(4)').hide();
} else {
  $('.showmore').hide();
}

$('.showmore').on('click', function(e) {
  $(".block-layered-nav .block-content dl dd ul li:gt(4)").toggle().parent();
  alert(myparent('li'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block block-layered-nav block-layered-nav--no-filters">
<div class="block-content toggle-content">
  <dl id="narrow-by-list">
    <dt>Wat</dt>
    <dd>
      <ul>
        <li class="list-group-item"><span>Moi1</span><a href="#">Hout</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><span>Moi2</span><a href="#">Hout</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><span>Moi3</span><a href="#">Hout</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><span>Moi3</span><a href="#">Hout</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><span>Moi3</span><a href="#">Hout</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><span>Moi3</span><a href="#">Hout</a></li>
      </ul>
      <button onclick="" class="showmore">
          Laat meer zien
      </button>
    </dd>
    <dt>Uitstraling</dt>
    <dd>
      <ul>
        <li class="list-group-item"><span>Moi4</span><a href="#">Hout</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><span>Moi5</span><a href="#">Hout</a></li>
      </ul>
      <button onclick="" class="showmore">
    Laat meer zien
  </button>
    </dd>
    <dt>Glans</dt>
    <dd>
      <ul>
        <li class="list-group-item"><span>Moi6</span><a href="#">Hout</a></li>
        <li class="list-group-item"><span>Moi7</span><a href="#">Hout</a></li>
      </ul>
      <button onclick="" class="showmore">
          Laat meer zien
       </button>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: use this context to refer to current click item

Comment: Please fix your code according to the console errors now I made a snippet for you

Comment: Fixed the error

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/d6nkt016/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fellow Dutchmen here, working on something with wood hm? Haha.

The problem is the following: you're counting ALL your `li`'s in all your `ul`'s and adding them up into one variable `count`. What you'll have to do is, for each `ul` count how many `li`'s there are in it, and if it's more than 5, ONLY add a `show more` button under that very `ul` (right now, you're adding show more buttons everywhere if one of the lists contains 5 items or more). I fixed your code for you. Hope it helps! https://jsfiddle.net/admn32oe/12/

Veel succes verder! :-)

```js
$('.block-layered-nav .block-content dl dd ul').each( function () {

  var count = $(this).children('li').length;

  if (count > 5) {
    $(this).next('.showmore').show();
    $(this).find('li:gt(4)').hide();
  } else {
    $(this).next('.showmore').hide();
  }

}); 

$('.showmore').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).siblings("ul").children('li:gt(4)').toggle().parent();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block block-layered-nav block-layered-nav--no-filters">
  <div class="block-content toggle-content">
    <dl id="narrow-by-list">
      <dt>Wat</dt>
      <dd>
        <ul>
          <li class="list-group-item"><span>Moi1</span><a href="#">Hout</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><span>Moi2</span><a href="#">Hout</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><span>Moi3</span><a href="#">Hout</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><span>Moi3</span><a href="#">Hout</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><span>Moi3</span><a href="#">Hout</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><span>Moi3</span><a href="#">Hout</a></li>

        </ul>
         <button onclick="" class="showmore">
            Laat meer zien
        </button>
      </dd>
      <dt>Uitstraling</dt>
       <dd>
        <ul>
          <li class="list-group-item"><span>Moi4</span><a href="#">Hout</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><span>Moi5</span><a href="#">Hout</a></li>
        </ul>
            <button onclick="" class="showmore">
      Laat meer zien
    </button>
      </dd>
      <dt>Glans</dt>
       <dd>
        <ul>
          <li class="list-group-item"><span>Moi6</span><a href="#">Hout</a></li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><span>Moi7</span><a href="#">Hout</a></li>
        </ul>
         <button onclick="" class="showmore">
            Laat meer zien
         </button>
      </dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: U wordt bedankt! haha

Answer (score 0):

I would consider this:

```
$('.showmore').each(function() { 
  var $parent = $(this).closest("dd"),
         $lis = $parent.find("li"),
         len  = $lis.length;
  $parent.find("li:gt(4)").hide(); // or something cleverer perhaps using eq
  $(this).toggle(len);
}).on("click",function() { 
  $(this).siblings("ul").children('li:gt(4)').toggle();
});
```